# Project on rain detection and home automation system

Tags: power-electronics

I am doing a project on rain detection and closing of windows. It is school based project. I am using an arduino, a rain sensor and a motor. Kindly advice on the right motor to use. And also, do I need a motor controller?

Comment: Welcome to engineering SE. Can you describe the size of windows, weight, and how they are attached. If you can post a picture too. The size of the motor is base on mechanical properties of the window. The motor controller is base on the size of the motor.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting ahead of youself.  First you have to gather the specs and requirements.  Only then can you choose parts.

For example, motors come with different power and torque ratings.  Without knowing how much force it takes to open and close a window, how far the travel is, and how fast you want the window opened/closed, you don't know what the motor needs to do.  You therefore can't pick one.  In addition to knowing what it takes to actuate the window, you also have to decide on the mechanical coupling of the motor to the window.  That may cause a different torque/power tradeoff.

I'd probably start by thinking of the mechanical coupling first.  How are you going to take the rotary motion of a motor to ultimately move the window.  Then you can take a stab at finding a motor.  This could be a iterative process.  For example, let's say you use a rack and pinion.  You lay out the basic mechanical system, but then pick a pinion gear size to match a available motor.